# Logic in vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

I have two vector spaces A and B.
is it right to say the following?

1)AUB<=A+B
2)span(A+B)=AUB(im not looking for the minimal,just if its right to say)
3)BASE(A+B)<=BASE(A)U(BASEB)<=BASE(A)+BASE(B)

im bit stuck with some proves that i have to do,thanks.

Comment: What? Groups??? Use [Mathjax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for operations such as $A + B$ and $A \cup B$ to be defined, $A$ and $B$ need to be subspaces of the same larger vector space.  So, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $V$.

1. Indeed, $A \cup B \subseteq A+B$
2. It is not the case that span$(A+B) = A \cup B$; in particular, $A \cup B$ is not necessarily a subspace.  It **is** true, however, that $A + B = $ span$(A \cup B)$
3. BASE$(A)$ is not an operation that I've ever heard of, and (if the point of the operation is to produce a basis of the argument) I don't believe such an operator can be consistently defined.

Comment: Can you explain please why 1 is true,i cant understand the logic,i dont want prove of that,only underatanding why. I think im not understanding the difference between + and U

Comment: For example: in $V = \Bbb R^2$, take $A$ to be the $x$-axis and $B$ to be the $y$-axis.  $A + B = \Bbb R^2$; it's the smallest subspace that contains both $A$ and $B$.  However, $A \cup B = \{(x,y): x=0 \text{ or } y = 0\}$; it's the union of two sets, which in this case fails to be a subspace.